# Chinese on MacTex2018, simple example

Tags: pdftex, cjk, chinese, ctex

I just installed MacTex2018 (because I was having trouble with TexLive2016).

My issue is related to chinese chars. May I ask for a simple example?

In the end I would like to have just some chinese words in the document which will mostly be in english.

I tried this:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\begin{document}
你好
\end{document}
```

Then got:

```
$ pdflatex report.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./report.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexart.cls
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def))
Document Class: ctexart 2018/01/28 v2.4.12 Chinese adapter for class article (C
TEX)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexpatch.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everysel.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/config/ctexopts.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/engine/ctex-engine-pdftex.de
f (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/CJKutf8.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/CJK.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/mule/MULEenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/CJK.enc))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjkpunct/CJKpunct.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjkpunct/CJKpunct.spa))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/CJKspace.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexspa.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/CJKfntef.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/CJKulem.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zhnumber/zhnumber.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zhnumber/zhnumber-utf8.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/scheme/ctex-scheme-chinese-a
rticle.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/config/ctex-name-utf8.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctex-c5size.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/fontset/ctex-fontset-mac.def

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! Critical ctex error: "fontset-unavailable"
! 
! CTeX fontset `mac' is unavailable in current mode.
! 
! See the ctex documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.47   }

? 
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/config/ctex.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/UTF8/UTF8.bdg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/UTF8/UTF8.enc)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/UTF8/UTF8.chr)
(./report.aux) ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/UTF8/c70song.fd)
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./report.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+32/600 --dpi 632 cyberb59
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for cyberb59.
mktexpk: perhaps cyberb59 is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file cyberb59): Font cyberb59 at 632 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Perhaps I should try to solve the critical error part `Critical ctex error: "fontset-unavailable"`, but it points me to a chinese document, http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/language/chinese/ctex/ctex.pdf, (Wouldn't make sense to have a english version of it?).

Answer (score 4):

You may use `xelatex` or `lualatex` to compile, rather than `pdflatex`. On macOS, the default Chinese fonts used by `ctex` are OpenType fonts, which cannot be (easily) used by pdfLaTeX.

The developers of `ctex` have considered to provide an English version of document, but they haven't done it for some reasons. However, you may ask them directly via [GitHub](https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit).